# How do I prove that these are equal using laws of logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-arithmetic

Prove that $\lnot(p\lor(\lnot p\land q)$ is equivalent to $\lnot p\land\lnot q$

I always end up at $\lnot p$, here's my solution:
\begin{equation}
\lnot(p\lor(\lnot p\land q))=\lnot p\land\lnot q
\end{equation}
let $\lnot p\land q$ be $r$
\begin{gather}
\lnot(p\lor r)=\lnot p\land\lnot q\\
\lnot p\land\lnot r=\lnot p\land\lnot q\\
\lnot p\land\lnot(\lnot p\land q)=\lnot p\land\lnot q\\
\lnot p\land(p\land\lnot q)=\lnot p\land\lnot q\\
\lnot p=\lnot p\land\lnot q
\end{gather}
not equal.

Comment: Mistake is in going from the third-last line to the second-last line, you're forgetting that the "and" becomes an "or" on negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\neg P \wedge \neg ( \neg P \wedge Q)$

= $\neg P \wedge (P \vee \neg Q) \qquad \text{(De Morgan's law)}$

= $(\neg P \wedge P) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \qquad \text{(ditributivity)}$

= $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$

The conclusion is justified by the fact that $\neg P \wedge P$ is paradoxical, hence $(\neg P \wedge P) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ is true if and only if $\neg P \wedge \neg Q$ is.

Comment: Sir Phil, you used idempotent on ¬P turned to  (¬P∧P)?

Comment: @nmab95 I used distributivity of "and" over "or"

Comment: Sir @Phil how about this? Prove that (z ^ w) v (–z ^ w) v (z ^ –w) is equivalent to z v w.

What I did was to let (z ^ w) be a:

= a v (–z ^ w) v (z ^ –w)

= (a v -z) ^ (a v w) v (z ^ –w)

= ((z ^ w) v -z) ^ ((z ^ w) v w) v (z ^ –w) <<Substitute value of a

and then I got confused. Am I on the right track??

Answer (score 0):

Using an equational style (Boolean algebra identities at work)

$\neg (p \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) =  \neg ((p \vee \neg p) \wedge (p \vee q))$  -- Distributivity

$\neg (p \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) =  \neg (\top \wedge (p \vee q))$

$\neg (p \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) =  \neg  (p \vee q)$

$\neg (p \vee (\neg p \wedge q)) =  \neg  p \wedge \neg q$     -- De Morgan